# iPhone 6s Bluetooth Disconnects when Music & Video Plays

Tags: ios

Bluetooth connects fine with all Bluetooth devices like car, earphone, speaker etc. But when either music or videos starts, the Bluetooth gets disconnected immediately.

It works fine when connected to PS4 controller over Bluetooth.

I'm running on iOS 12.1.2 on iPhone 6s Jailbroken with latest unc0ver. The Bluetooth gets disconnected when in unjailbroken state too.

I've tried all methods to reset network settings, pairing and unpairing all devices to no avail. Before I do a factory reset, just wondering if there's anything I can do to verify it's not a hardware problem.